# Filtering a list using $.grep() based on a custom filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I would like to filter out certain objects from a list based on some conditions:

```
var list = [
    { mode: 1, type: 'foo' }, 
    { mode: 2, type: 'foo' }, 
    { mode: 3, type: 'foo' }, // remove this item
    { mode: 1, type: 'bar' }, 
    { mode: 2, type: 'bar' },
    { mode: 3, type: 'bar' }
];

var blah = $.grep(list, function(x){

    if(x.type === 'foo')
        return x.mode !== 3;
    else
        return true;
});

console.log('result 1:', blah);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/65LeJ/

This works just as intented.

My issue is that I have a filter which is sent from my server as JSON:

```
var blah = list;

var filter = [
    { propertyName: 'mode', value: 3 }, 
    { propertyName: 'type', value: 'foo' }
];

$.each(filter, function(k, filterRow){

    blah = $.grep(blah, function(listItem){
        return listItem[filterRow.propertyName] === filterRow.value;
    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/65LeJ/1/

This will obviously filter out too much, but it's just to give you an idea on how it's working.

What I would like to know is your suggestions on how the filter should look like to filter out the same amount of rows as in my first example.

And no, I don't want to pass an expression and use `eval()`.

Please let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: Uhm, I am not quite sure if I understand correctly, but I think you should use `!=` in your filter?

Comment: What do you mean by "filter out the same amount of rows as in my first example".

Comment: @Skarlinski First example return 5 rows, second returns 1.

Comment: @Johan Because you are only allowing this one with your filter options. What you do is, you are asking for an object where mode equals 3 and the according value equals 3.

Comment: @DanLee No, I want to remove objects with type "foo" and value not equal to "3".

Comment: I guess I know what you want, but you're implementing it the other way around.

Comment: @DanLee I got your point. But it's because the filter I'm receiving is actually "what to keep" and not "what to remove" which I'm not a big fan of. I'm not the one generating it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd be better off using `[].filter` and `[].every`.

Here's my solution:

```
var list = [
    { mode: 1, type: 'foo' }, 
    { mode: 2, type: 'foo' }, 
    { mode: 3, type: 'foo' }, // remove this item
    { mode: 1, type: 'bar' }, 
    { mode: 2, type: 'bar' },
    { mode: 3, type: 'bar' }
];

var blah = list;

var filter = [{ propertyName: 'mode', value: 3 }, { propertyName: 'type', value: 'foo' }];

var filtered = list.filter(function(listItem) {
    return !filter.every(function(filterItem) {
        return listItem[filterItem.propertyName] === filterItem.value;
    });
});

console.log(filtered);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Dogbert/65LeJ/2/

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about any of those two methods. I suppose I need to use a polyfill for them in order to use them in IE7?

Comment: Was doing something similar. You answered it before me. +1

Comment: How do you handle `filterItem.value` if it's an array?

Comment: @Johan, it can be an Array too? What do you want to do in that case? Deep equality test?

Comment: @Dogbert Something like `$.inArray(listItem[filterItem.propertyName], filterItem.value) > -1` I suppose...

Comment: @Johan, hmm, that wasn't specified in your post. Just change the `listItem[filterItem.propertyName] === ...` into an if statement which does Array element check if `.value` is an Array, otherwise does `===`?

Comment: @Dogbert I know it wasn't specified. But some array checks made the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

And if you want to keep $.each !!!

```
var list = [
    { mode: 1, type: 'foo' }, 
    { mode: 2, type: 'foo' }, 
    { mode: 3, type: 'foo' }, // remove this item
    { mode: 1, type: 'bar' }, 
    { mode: 2, type: 'bar' },
    { mode: 3, type: 'bar' }
];

var filter = [
    { propertyName: 'mode', value: 3 }, 
    { propertyName: 'type', value: 'foo' }
];

var blah = $.grep(list, function(x){
    var result = true;    

    $.each(filter, function(index, element) {
        result &= (x[element.propertyName] === element.value)
    });

    return !result;
});

console.log('result 1:', blah);
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, interesting solution. Never seen `&=`. How does it work?

Comment: `a &= true` is same as `a = a & true`

Comment: What if `element.value` is an array?

Comment: @7stud Yeah, I'm thinking about moving some of the logic to the server. Old versions of IE doesn't handle many iterations very well.

Answer (score 1):

```
var list = [
    { mode: 1, type: 'foo' }, 
    { mode: 2, type: 'foo' }, 
    { mode: 3, type: 'foo' }, 
    { mode: 1, type: 'bar' }, 
    { mode: 2, type: 'bar', name: 'Agnes'}, // remove this item
    { mode: 3}
];

var filter = [
    { propertyName: 'mode', value: 2 }, 
    { propertyName: 'type', value: 'bar' },
    { propertyName: 'name', value: 'Agnes' }
];

var filter_obj = {};
var i;

for(i=0; i<filter.length; ++i) {
  var obj = filter[i];
  filter_obj[obj.propertyName] = obj.value;
}

var results = [];
var filter_len = Object.keys(filter_obj).length;

NEXT_OBJECT:
for(i=0; i<list.length; ++i) {
  obj = list[i];

  if(Object.keys(obj).length != filter_len) {
    results.push(obj);
  }
  else {
    for(key in obj) {
      if(obj[key] != filter_obj[key]) {
        results.push(obj);
        continue NEXT_OBJECT;
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(results);

--output:--
[Object { mode=1, type="foo"}, 
 Object { mode=2, type="foo"}, 
 Object { mode=3, type="foo"}, 
 Object { mode=1, type="bar"}, 
 Object { mode=3}]
```

Comment: Thanks for an alternative solution.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach, if you don't mind running afoul of Crockford's "Eval is Evil" by using a Function constructor, is something like this:

```
var filter = [
    {propertyName: 'mode', value: 3}, 
    {propertyName: 'type', value: 'foo'}
];

var makeGrepFn = function(filter) {
    return new Function("listItem", (function() {
        var body = [], idx = -1;
        while (++idx < filter.length) {
            body.push("if ('' + listItem['" + 
                    filter[idx].propertyName + "'] !== '" + 
                    filter[idx].value + "') {return true;}");
        }
        body.push("return false;");
        return "    " + body.join("\n    ");
    }()));
};

var grepFn = makeGrepFn(filter);

var filtered = $.grep(list, grepFn);
```

This has all sorts of limitations.  It compares strings and numbers as equivalent.  Although that could be fixed, it would significantly complicate the code.  It doesn't work with more complicated objects, just ones with primitive properties, but it is still a somewhat interesting approach.

`grepFn` will end up being something equivalent to this:

```
function (listItem) {
    if ('' + listItem['mode'] !== '3') {return true;}
    if ('' + listItem['type'] !== 'foo') {return true;}
    return false;
}
```

Obviously you could do something like this to use with `Array.prototype.filter` instead of `jQuery.grep` if you choose.  You'd simply have to reverse the `true`s and `false`s above.

Comment: Sure, eval is evil. But eval != function constructor. Thanks for the input.

Comment: @Johan: I'm not sure Crockford would agree.  But for myself, I keep finding powerful uses for the Function contructor.

Comment: Agreed. It can be really useful in some cases!

Answer (score 1):

As Dogbert said `filter` and `every` does the job. However, it's a very slow method. This is the sort of thing where SQL queries are helpful. Consider you have the following table in SQL:

```
      List
+------+------+
| Mode | Type |
+------+------+
|    1 |  foo |
+------+------+
|    2 |  foo |
+------+------+
|    3 |  foo |
+------+------+
|    1 |  bar |
+------+------+
|    2 |  bar |
+------+------+
|    3 |  bar |
+------+------+
```

You can execute either one of the following two queries to get the data you want:

**Query 1:** Constructive (creates a new table)

```
SELECT * FROM List WHERE Mode != '3' AND Type != 'foo';
```

**Query 2:** Destructive (delete rows from the table)

```
DELETE FROM List WHERE Mode = '3' AND Type = 'foo';
```

---

Of course, JavaScript is not SQL. However we can use these two SQL queries as guidelines to create two functions in JavaScript that generate the correct result.

**Function 1:** Constructive

```
function filter(table, conditions) {
    var rows = table.length, length = conditions.length, result = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < rows;) {
        var row = table[i++];

        for (var j = 0; j < length;) {
            var condition = conditions[j++];

            if (row[condition.propertyName] !== condition.value) {
                result.push(row);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

**Function 2:** Destructive

```
function remove(table, conditions) {
    var rows = table.length, length = conditions.length, result = [];

    loop: for (var i = 0; i < rows;) {
        var row = table[i++];

        for (var j = 0; j < length;) {
            var condition = conditions[j++];
            if (row[condition.propertyName] !== condition.value)
                continue loop;
        }

        table.splice(--i, 1);
        rows--;
    }
}
```

---

Now given a table and a list of conditions you may either `filter` or `remove` the rows you don't want.

Consider you have the following table:

```
var table = [
    { mode: 1, type: 'foo' }, 
    { mode: 2, type: 'foo' }, 
    { mode: 3, type: 'foo' }, // remove this item
    { mode: 1, type: 'bar' }, 
    { mode: 2, type: 'bar' },
    { mode: 3, type: 'bar' }
];
```

Given the following conditions:

```
var conditions = [
    { propertyName: 'mode', value: 3 }, 
    { propertyName: 'type', value: 'foo' }
];
```

You could either do:

```
var result = filter(table, conditions);
```

Or you could do:

```
remove(table, conditions);
```

Personally I prefer `filter` over `remove` (just in case you need the original table).

---

Okay, so how are these methods better than Dogbert's solution? The answer is because they are much faster. The reason they are so fast is because:

1. You don't use `[].filter` which is slow because you execute a callback for every row in the table.
2. You don't use `[].every` which is also slow because you execute a callback for every condition.

In essence both `filter` and `remove` are the same Dogbert's solution. However since they are handcrafted and don't use callbacks the execute much faster. See the results for yourself:

http://jsperf.com/filter-and-every-vs-filter-vs-remove

Answer (score 1):

If can't use `Array` methods like `.filter` and `.every`, but have `jQuery` then you can try this:

```
var filtered = $.grep(list, function(el) {
  return $.grep(filter, function(filterEl) {
    return el[filterEl.propertyName] === filterEl.value;
  }).length !== 2;
});
```

It's a very specific solution to your problem, but it's easier to reason about than other answers.